# Assigning a variable value to anchor tag to create a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign the value of variable `a` in an anchor tag to create a hyperlink

```
<html>
<head> 
  <script> 
    var a="www.google.com";    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = "i want the value of a  here" / > 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: that's totally not  clear can you please add more description

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ID to your element and modify the attribute by doing something like :

```
const el = document.getelementbyid("thehtmlid")
el.attribute("href", myvalue)
```

Functions probably not named like this but it should be close enough to help u

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty anchor tag and then update href value using javasript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div id="root"></div>
  <a id="link" href=""> A</a>
  <script>
    let a = "https://www.google.com";

    document.getElementById('link').href = a;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```